# Looping over heterogeneous collection

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, domain-driven-design

The example is as follows: I have a `Box` that needs to be filled with some `Thing`s. I'm interested only in weight of each thing. Also, beside weight, I need to correctly identify the thing that I'm measuring. Each thing type has different Id type. In this case I have toys and fruits, which have `ToyId` and `FruitId` respectively. In the end, I need to be able to print thing identifier and thing weight.

Question: Is it somehow possible to access specific methods on `ThingId`s without using instanceof operator (as in example)?

```
class Color{}
interface ThingId {}

class FruitId implements ThingId {
    String name;    //"apple", "orange", ...
    FruitId(String name){  this.name = name; }
    String getName(){ return this.name; }
}

class ToyId implements ThingId {
    String shape;   //"square", "circle", ...
    Color color;    //"red", "blue"...
    ToyId(String shape, Color color){ this.shape = shape; this.color = color; }
    String getShape(){ return this.shape; }
    Color getColor(){ return this.color; }
}

class Thing{
    ThingId thingId;
    Integer weight;
    public Thing(ThingId thingId, Integer weight){
        this.thingId = thingId;
        this.weight = weight;
    }
    ThingId getThingId(){ return this.thingId; }
    Integer getWeight(){ return this.weight; }
}

class Box {
    Set<Thing> things = new HashSet<>();

    void addThing(Thing thing){
        this.things.add(thing);
    }

    Collection<Thing> getThings(){
        return this.things;
    }
}

class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FruitId appleId = new FruitId("apple");
        Thing apple = new Thing(appleId, 1);
        ToyId cubeId = new ToyId("square", new Color());
        Thing cube = new Thing(cubeId, 22);

        Box box = new Box();
        box.addThing(apple);
        box.addThing(cube);

        for(Thing t : box.getThings()){
            System.out.print("Thing Id is: ");
            if(t.getThingId() instanceof FruitId) { //any other possibility than using instance of?
                process((FruitId)t.getThingId());
            }
            if(t.getThingId() instanceof ToyId){    //any other possibility than using instance of?
                process((ToyId)t.getThingId());
            }
            System.out.println("Weight is : " + t.getWeight());
        }
    }

    static void process(FruitId fruitId){
        System.out.println(fruitId.getName());
    }

    static void process(ToyId toyId){
        System.out.println(toyId.getShape() + toyId.getColor());
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

OK, I think Visitor pattern could be useful here:

```
class Color{}
interface ThingId {
    void visitThingId(ThingIdVisitor visitor);
}

class FruitId implements ThingId {
    String name;    //"apple", "orange", ...
    FruitId(String name){  this.name = name; }
    String getName(){ return this.name; }

    @Override
    public void visitThingId(ThingIdVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.process(this);
    }
}

class ToyId implements ThingId {
    String shape;   //"square", "circle", ...
    Color color;    //"red", "blue"...
    ToyId(String shape, Color color){ this.shape = shape; this.color = color; }
    String getShape(){ return this.shape; }
    Color getColor(){ return this.color; }

    @Override
    public void visitThingId(ThingIdVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.process(this);
    }
}

class Thing{
    ThingId thingId;
    Integer weight;
    public Thing(ThingId thingId, Integer weight){
        this.thingId = thingId;
        this.weight = weight;
    }
    ThingId getThingId(){ return this.thingId; }
    Integer getWeight(){ return this.weight; }
}

class Box {
    Set<Thing> things = new HashSet<>();

    void addThing(Thing thing){
        this.things.add(thing);
    }

    Collection<Thing> getThings(){
        return this.things;
    }
}

class ThingIdVisitor{
    void process(FruitId fruitId){
        System.out.println(fruitId.getName());
    }

    void process(ToyId toyId){
        System.out.println(toyId.getShape() + toyId.getColor());
    }
}

class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FruitId appleId = new FruitId("apple");
        Thing apple = new Thing(appleId, 1);
        ToyId cubeId = new ToyId("square", new Color());
        Thing cube = new Thing(cubeId, 22);

        Box box = new Box();
        box.addThing(apple);
        box.addThing(cube);

        for(Thing t : box.getThings()){
            System.out.print("Thing Id is: ");

            t.getThingId().visitThingId(new ThingIdVisitor());

            System.out.println("Weight is : " + t.getWeight());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ThingId` should be named `ThingType`

Comment: @bojanv55 you must identify the common behavior about all `process()`es and extract it to a unique place (might be a distinct Processor object, might be the `Thing` itself). Then the shape of what it operates on will appear naturally and from it you can derive the abstracted type you need.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really get what you're trying to achieve. First of all, I don't get the use of the interface `ThingId`. Second, I think you're a bit confused about interfaces and inheritance. If I were you, I'd look up [polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html).

Anyway, I propose you remove the `ThingId` interface and let the `FruitId` and `ToyId` classes extend the `Thing` class. As your collection only exists of `Thing`s, and as your `Fruit` and `Toy` classes all extend this `Thing` class and thus implement the `getWeight()` method, you should not use `instanceof` anymore.

But please, read up on [polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html).

Comment: `ThingId` is just marker interface for readability (so i don't use `Object thingId;` inside `Thing`). Also, here I favor composition over inheritance. Don't see any benefits in extending over this solution. Also, if there is tomorrow `SuperNewThing`, I can reuse same Ids inside and not create `SuperNewThingFruit`, `SuperNewThingToy` ...

Comment: I can't think of any way why you would favor composition over inheritance in this case. This is a textbook example for inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

your interface `ThingId` must provide the respective methods that you want to have.

If you simple want to print out information, then you can use like a simple

```
public String getInformation();
```

Then the implementations can return the information that is relevant for them and you can simply work with `ThingId` in your application code.

BTW: As you are storing your `Thing`s in a `HashSet` make sure to implement `equals` and `hashCode` in all `Thing` implementations

Also I dont really see, why you need a `Thing` and a `ThingId`, as `ThingId` seems a bit more than a simple id and actually a thing. So for me it seems that `ThingId` is redundant and all can be achieved by the having different `Thing`s

Comment: OK. Instead getting String, I need to serialize this to XML without using existing libraries (that I guess use instanceof?). So to get something like `<FruitId>apple</FruitId><Weight>1</Weight> and <ToyId shape="square", color=""></ToyId><Weight>22</Weight>`

Comment: then you have a method like `public String getSerializedForm()' that the serializer then can process.

Comment: Inside ThingId? But then ThingId knows about serialization which should not be the case?

Comment: It depends on the way you serialize the xml.Somehow the ThingId must provide the serializer the information it requires. How ? As said, depends on how you serialize

Comment: OK. So in this case, if I want to externalize it, I must use instanceof...

Comment: no in neither case you need the instanceof. What you need is to find the right way to define a common method in the interface, which satisfies your requirements. Then you can use the interface method in the application

Answer (score 1):

Since you are calling the same method `process` on both the instance types, why not add that method to `ThingId` interface itself.

By doing so, you could just call:

```
t.getThingId().process();
```

Instead of finding the instance type and calling respective methods.

Comment: it is an option of course (same as Emerson said about method getSerializedForm()). But I don't like that solution since then `ThingId` needs to know about processing (serialization).